# Неверная ошибка

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

Выводит такую ошибку:

> ValidationError: Contact validation failed: phone: Path `phone` (680175919) is more than maximum allowed value (14).

Из неё видно что она не совсем верная, максимальное значения 14, а тут 9, вот схема:

```
const contact = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 15},
    surname: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 100},
    phone: {type: Number, required: true, min: 9, max: 14}
}, {versionKey: false});
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: Или указывайте границы для именно типа число (от 1000000000 до 9999999999), или меняйте тип на строковый.

Comment: @Akina там наверное упрется в лимиты, не?

Comment: и в Number смысла особого смысла хранить номер нет, так как у вас нет необходимых операций подобного типа, вы просто храните номер телефона и используете без каких-либо операций математических и сравнений

Comment: Что же тут неверного? 680 миллионов - это ведь действительно больше, чем 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Номер телефона в `Number` хранить плохо, лучше в `String`, а то сейчас в схеме указано, что минимальное число 9, а максимальное 14

Comment: получается, вот там для `String` можно указать нужный `maxlength`